# TabBar Android como criar

Tags: android

Alguem tem exemplo de como criar abas no Android, estilo do WhatsApp?

Segue o exemplo que desejo:

[image: https://fs02.androidpit.info/userfiles/4774964/image/AndroidPIT-WhatsApp-Material-Design-update-1-w782.jpg]

No exemplo, quero criar as abas Calls, Chats e Contacts

E por fim, na segunda imagem, como adicionar uma foto na barra e do lado o nome da pessoa?

So preciso de um exemplo.

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Esse esquema com as abas do WhatsApp, chama-se **ViewPager**.

Você pode ver um exemplo dos códigos e até baixar um projeto e importar no seu Android Studio pra ver como é feito, na própria documentação do Android, segue o link:

**https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html**

Já para o caso da foto do lado do nome, é um pouco mais complicado, você precisa pesquisar por listview/recyclerview com um adapter customizado.

Não compensa eu te mandar links com exemplos aqui, pois eles podem ser alterados sem prévio aviso, então vale mais a pena você mesma pesquisar no Google sobre **listview with custom adapter**.

Lembre-se de sempre pesquisar em inglês, o conteúdo encontrado será muito mais rico do que se você pesquisar em português.

Qualquer dúvida que você tiver pesquisando sobre esses assuntos da uma perguntada aqui no tópico que a gente vai te ajudando.

Abraços.